# Not writing String to file with formating

Tags: java, string, filewriter

My string looks like this before printing: "goo\nfoo\nblah\n".  It prints that fine with System.out.println but when I do this(where expand is my String):

```
     try {
         PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("blah.txt", "UTF-8");
         writer.println(expand);
         writer.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It doesn't print the newlines.
How do I get it to write to the file with the newline characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using Windows, replace your \n with \r\n.

Comment: or better use System.getProperty("line.separator")